# BigQuery: Compare mm/yyyy date to specific date and CURRENT_DATE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have dates formatted as `mm/yyyy` (such as 11/2018) in a column called `actual_date`. I need to select all records where `actual_date < 2000/01/01` and `actual_date > SystemDate` (or more exactly `CURRENT_DATE()`). Based on this select I want to calculate the % of records that are in this situation. Unfortunatly `actual_date` is declared as String in the database, so I need to cast it as date.

I searched for different solutions on the internet, but some of them did not apply to BigQuery. In principle I probably need a line of code close to the following. Yet, everything I try does not work. BigQuery either does not recognise the function (tried using `CONVERT` for example) or is saying that it can not compare the dates.

The code is configured as such because I calculate is like this: All Records - Correct Records (dates between 2000/01/01 and CURRENT_DATE()) divided by All Records. This should give the % of incorrect records (dates below 2000/01/01 and above the CURRENT_DATE()). NULL is an acceptable value, for this reason it is included as a correct value in the calculation.

```
   SELECT
   ROUND ((
   COUNT(1) - 
   (SUM (CASE WHEN (actual_date IS NULL) IS TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + 
    SUM (CASE WHEN (CAST actual_date AS DATE) > 2000/01/01) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    +  
    SUM (CASE WHEN (CAST actual_date AS DATE) < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END)))
    * 100 / COUNT(1), 3)
   FROM `project.dataset.datatable`
   WHERE country_code = 'country1'
```

The result should be % of actual_date that is less than 2000/01/01 and above the CURRENT_DATE().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [how to] Compare mm/yyyy date to specific date and CURRENT_DATE

You should first parse date out of string as `PARSE_DATE('%m/%Y', '11/2018')` - note: simple CAST as DATE does not fly here
Then you can compare with other dates like for example

```
PARSE_DATE('%m/%Y', actual_date) BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

So, your final query could look something like below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ROUND (
  (COUNT(1) - COUNTIF(PARSE_DATE('%m/%Y', actual_date) BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()))
  * 100 / COUNT(1), 3)
FROM `project.dataset.datatable`
WHERE country_code = 'country1'
```